# Whitespaces in scraping results (python)

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website with python2.7 and beautifulsoup4. The code I'm using works on one machine, on the other, I get the resulting 'soup' with three whitespaces added between the letters. I get something like the following (both in terminal as in eclipse/pydev. Any idea what's causing this?

```
               i   f       (   w   i   n   d   o   w   .   D   o   m   L   o   a   d   e   d   )   
           {   
               D   o   m   L   o   a   d   e   d   .   l   o   a   d   (   f   u   n   c   t   i   o   n   (   )   {   b   a   n   n   e   r   S   y   n   c   (   '   t   b   '   )   ;   }   )   ;   

               d   o   c   u   m   e   n   t   .   w   r   i   t   e   (   '   d   i   v       i   d   =   "   d   o   m   L   o   a   d   e   d   "       s   t   y   l   e   =   "   d   i   s   p   l   a   y   :   n   o   n   e   "   &gt;   \   /   d   i   v   &gt;   '   )   ;   
           }   
       /   s   c   r   i   p   t   &gt;   
       !   -   -       S   e   r   v   e   r   :       P   h   o   b   o   s   ,       S   e   r   v   e   r       t   i   m   e   :       0   ,   0   9   2   7       s       (   C   :       0   ,   0   5   2   0   ;       Q   :       7   ;       0   ,   0   0   2   2   ;       E   :       5   2   ;       0   ,   0   3   1   1       s   ,       M   :       3   ;       0   ,   0   0   1   1       s   ,       A   :       0   ;       0   ,   0   0   0   0       s   )   ,       M   e   m   :       1   2   3   0   1       K   B   ,       E   n   g   i   n   e   s   :       (   S   )       p   h   o   b   o   s       (   5   2   )       -   -   &gt;   
   /   b   o   d   y   &gt;
```

/   h   t   m   l   >

Comment: Relevant snippets of code will help you get a better answer. Also, if you try and make your example as small as possible, you may stumble upon the answer yourself while preparing your example.

Comment: @Nathan Seriously, it can't be more relevant to show what's going wrong in the output than by showing a snipped of the output. The code was obviously not the problem, neither was the scraped site. As mentioned clearly in the text, it worked flawless on another machine. I've left the whitespaces in the snipped because those are the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very possible that two machines have installed different HTML parser libraries, please check this [link](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#other-parser-problems). As you know, different parsers may have different parse result, esp. for those ill-formed HTML.

Comment: Zeng Thanks. Was so convinced that I copied the environment on both machines almost exactly, that I didn't think about the most obvious. Working like a charm now. Can't believe I spent so much time on this one :s.